# How to capture home button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-homebutton

In my application, I would like to open login screen if user click home button but also want to maintain activity stack.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you can't get the home button click event

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to do the same. like you can not get the KeyDown event for the HOME key. but we can get the HOME key captured and  stay in the same screen by following code

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);

    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Comment: AFAIK Home key the only escaping point for the application. so we can not get the specific event. you need to change you application design a bit

Comment: This no longer works as of 4.0. The last comment on this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/trRI99-HszQ

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should override to home button:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    Intent new(this, login);
    start(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: KEYCODE_BACK is the Back button, not Home button.

Answer (score -5):

You cannot capture Home button click event definitely for security reasons.

However, you can do something along with actions taken by pressing Home button by overriding method `onNewIntent()`.